What does this mean that "each incoming byte affects roughly only one byte of the summing register no matter how wide it is?"
The author of A Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms writes, "with a simple summing formula, each incoming byte affects roughly only one byte of the summing register no matter how wide it is." What does that mean? Will you please provide an example showing an incoming byte affecting roughly only one byte of the summing register?
